# Function not working in Form Load, but works everywhere else

Tags: c#, winforms, function, datagridview, taglib-sharp

I'm using the function below to add items to a `DataGridView`.

```
void addFiles(List<string> files)
{
    foreach (var item in filesFound)
    {
        if (File.Exists(item))
         {
            fileList.Add(item);
            MessageBox.Show(item);
            string p = GetFolderPath(Personal) + @"\Music Database\";
            Directory.CreateDirectory(p);
            string file="";
            try
            {
                StreamReader read = new StreamReader(p + "musicdatabase.txt");
                file = read.ReadToEnd();
                read.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e.ToString().Contains(""))
                {
                    //add error code here later
                }
            }

            StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(p + "musicdatabase.txt");
            write.WriteLine(file + item);
            write.Close();

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(getTitle(item), getArtist(item), getDuration(item), item);
        }
        else
        {
            //add file not found error code here
        }
    }
}
```

The function works fine. It adds the details perfectly. `getTitle();`, `getArtist();` and `getDuration();` do what they say. They use TagLib# to get the details of audio files. The file path of the audio file gets written to a text file in the users documents.

The problem arises when I load the form: I read the text file as a whole, putting each line into a new index of `List<string> textlist = new List<string>();`. This is fine. The list has each line. I then run `addFiles(textlist);`. I launch the program and it loads, but nothing is added to the `DataGridView`.

I have a feeling it may be to do with the fact it might not be loaded when the Form_Load is triggered.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string p = GetFolderPath(Personal) + @"\Music Database\musicdatabase.txt";
    //MessageBox.Show(p);
    //MessageBox.Show(File.Exists(p).ToString());
    if (File.Exists(p))
    {
        string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(p);
        List<string> textlist = new List<string>();
        textlist = text.ToList();
        // -- THIS PROVES THE textlist LIST CONTAINS ITEMS --
        //foreach (var item in textlist)
        //{
        //MessageBox.Show(item);
        //MessageBox.Show(textlist[0]);
        //}
        //THIS IS THE PROBLEM
        addFiles(textlist);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I suggest filling in catch `clause` to see if an error occurs if nothing happens

Comment: This code does not belong in the Load event.  Makes it slow for no good reason.  And above all, it makes it risky on Win7, you won't see an exception.  Move it into the constructor.

Comment: @John Still no errors when I remove the `try{...} catch{...}`

Comment: @HansPassant This is just for me to test the code. I'm going to add an option for `Save...` and `Open...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
    foreach (var item in filesFound)
```

You are referencing what appears to be a global variable called filesFound,
rather than the variable `files` that is passed to the function.

Comment: That is the problem!

Comment: Glad I could help!